# Validate one input field to another input field in Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I have one input field, which is the sum of 4 fields. I want this sum field to equal another input field later in the form. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [validation constraint formula](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas.html#validations-and-alerts).

Say you sum field is called `sum`, and your other field is called `other`. Just write:

```
$sum = $other
```

as formula.

See also:

- [Validation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/validation.html)
- [Examples of formulas](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas-examples.html)